# Metadata missing from latest document version

Tags: 2010, document-library, managed-metadata, metadata

We have an issue with a document library whereby documents are losing their metadata, i.e. in View Properties, the metadata fields are empty. However if you click on version history, all of the metadata fields are there and populated. This is true even for documents with only one published version.

Any ideas how can this be restored?

We are also having issues with the search in this document library, whereby some documents do not appear in the results even if you type the exact name/title in the search field. Tried to reset index but did nothing. I am wondering if its worth nuking the library and recreating.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The latter issue with the search has been resolved - it related to Draft Item Security - as discussed in point 4. of this article by Harry Chen:

http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/why-sharepoint-2010-search-does-not.html

where "Draft Item Security"is set to "Only users who can edit items" - the indexer only crawls published versions, and minor versions are not published. Changing the setting to "Only users who can read items" has fixed the issue.

The metadata issue remains outstanding.

Comment: It sounds like your services aren't running properly, two errors both describe services. Check the windows logs for errors and warnings to do with services and the ULS logs as well. (Recommend ULS log viewer from codeplex for that job)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hugh. I have reviewed windows logs for service related errors and the only one with an issue is Forefront Identity Manager and this seems to be running ok now. 

The ULS logs are not giving me much, but they are quite verbose and difficult to navigate even with the log viewer.

In any case I have restarted the SP search service in case there was an issue with that. Are there any other windows services which may be particular to an SP metadata issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Metadata issue was related to the library's two content types having unmatching column names, which shows that the current default view in the library has an erroneous column from a content type which isn't used (link to document).

At some point the content type must have been added and configured with a different column name pointing at the same metadata term.