# Excel Documents dropping MetaData in a Document Library when edited

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, metadata, content-approval

Currently in our environment we have an approval based library that houses several documents, all categorized and utilizes Metadata columns to group and sort those documents. When an individual edits an Excel document from this library and then saves it, the original Metadata disappears and the document goes into draft. After the document is approved and released the Metadata is still gone. This issue does not occur with any other document types like Word or PowerPoint documents. Below is a screenshot of the version history on one of the Excel documents. The Metadata isn't cleared by the person. The person just opens up the document to edit, then saves the document. This issue doesn't seem to occur when content approval is disabled, however this is needed for this specific business process. No errors are displayed anywhere, be it inside SharePoint or Excel. Any assistance anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Platform: **SharePoint 2010 Foundation**

Settings: Content Approval: **On**

Versioning: **Major and Minor versions**

The only stackexchange I could find that was anywhere close to my situation was [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52434/metadata-missing-from-latest-document-version). There are two content types used, however the column names were not the same as stated in that Answer. 

[image: Screenshot of Version History]

Comment: Also to note, this is occurring on both .xls and .xlsx documents.